# How do I create a CI/CD pipeline for a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, docker, gitlab, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have the following setup:

- Local development environment on Mac OSX
- Remote cloud server on Ubuntu 22.04
- Gitlab for version control

How can I get a similar workflow like my Nuxt.js projects, where I develop locally, push to Gitlab and then have the latest commit automatically pushed to a staging server (the remote cloud server in my case)?

I have found the following resources regarding this topic but I'm not sure what the common / best practice is in building a CI/CD pipeline for Wordpress projects:

[Wordpress CI/CD pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558836/wordpress-ci-cd-pipeline)

[Continuous Delivery on Wordpress using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442204/continuous-delivery-on-wordpress-using-docker?rq=1)

[How can I put a database under git (version control)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control/28123546#28123546)

Is Docker the solution I am looking for or do I need other tools to create this pipeline?

I found this tutorial but I wanted to make sure the general approach is correct: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-wordpress-deployments-with-digitalocean-and-buddy

Thank you for your help!

Comment: My hosting provider had an option in the cpanel to create a webhook, I used that webhook with github to do what your are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your input, sadly my hosting provider doesn't have CPanel. Will look into the possibility of a webhook though.

Answer (score 0):

I create a CICD with jenkins, gitlab, docker, k8s.
in jenkins, you can use shell alternative for pipeline.

Comment: @kiu kiu Duck Pea could you share tutorial of how create CI CD with jenkis,gitlab,docker,k8s ? please?

Comment: @jonathasborges1 What is the problem you encountered?